# Random number generation in JSP using java

Tags: java, jsp

I want to generate random numbers in JSP.

I have created java code to generate a random number in a JSP page and output the random number in a textbox.

```
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%
Random rand = new Random();
int n = rand.nextInt(90000) + 10000;
System.out.println(n);
%>
<html>
    <body>
        ORDER NO  <input type="text" name="order" value=""/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not getting output for this code, can anyone suggest why?

Comment: Where do you expect the output? In the jsp or in the console?

Comment: @Thomas In textbox i expect the random no which is generated by the java code

Comment: For clarity, avoid writing Java code in the JSP itself, you should try to move that code to the controller, and add your variable to the model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out.println(n);` would write to the console, a JSP provides its own `out` writer, thus just write `out.println(n);`, i.e. without the `System` context.

Or if you want to write the number into your input field then use something like this:

```
ORDER NO  <input type="text" name="order" value="<%=n%>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an expression also to print it like
<%=n>

Comment: This looks just like the answer from 7 years ago -  if it isn't correct please edit it, if it's correct then please up-vote it.